# "Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run: bin/rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development " error. Error I get after installing devise gem

Tags: devise, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I am getting such an error. i run bin/rails db:migrate in terminal but i still get the same error. i am using postgresql.

Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run: bin/rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development

I think I got the error because there is email in my model and database.

the error I get in the terminal;

```
PG::DuplicateColumn: ERROR: column "email" of relation "staffs" already exists
: ALTER TABLE "staffs" ADD "email" character varying DEFAULT '' NOT NULL
```

The error I got on localhost;

```
Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run: bin/rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development
Extracted source (around line #579):

       # Raises <tt>ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError</tt> error if any migrations are pending.
       def check_pending!(connection = Base.connection)
         raise ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError if connection.migration_context.needs_migration?
       end

       def load_schema_if_pending!
```

Comment: yes but i keep getting the same error.i think i need to remove email column from model or database but i don't know how to do that

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not too descriptive, so let me add a list of tentative checks you could do to understand what's happening:

1. I'm assuming you have Postgres installed into your computer and running, right?
2. Are you able to log into Postgres from the command line? `psql -U postgres -W` and type your password. can you log into the database?
3. Do you have a database created for your app?
4. Do you have a user setup to that database with the proper `GRANT`s ?
5. Do you have the database connection properly set in your rails app?
6. When you start your server, do you see any additional log message that could hint to an issue with the database connection?

I hope these questions might help you as a checklist. But if it doesn't, please add to your question: your DB config file, a check of the Postgres database, a check of the user access, a log to the app when starting.

With kind regards,
Rogerio

Comment: Hello Guillaume. No worries. But did it work in the end?

Comment: Reading the additional info you provided, it seems to me that you are trying to create a relation column with a column name that already existis